# PHP CURL does not automatically add Content-Length header

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I've been stuck with this problem for a while now.
I have a simple proxy code to redirect queries from this PHP script to another application.

The thing is GET's work like a charm, but POST's don't. I've figured out that when I'm making a POST query from php-curl it doesn't attach the Content-Length header. Thus the actual app cant retrieve data from request and obviously fails to respond. So I decided to set it manually but now the actual app doesn't receive a full body but only a chunk of it for some reason, even though the content length is correct.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why doesn't curl set the header automatically? Since from what I read in docs it should be.
2. How can I properly calculate the content length? Because during tests I'm trying to even hardcode it based on a Content-Length header I get from postman when making queries to actual app.

Code is kinda simple:

```
function forward(FromRequest $request)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, IT_HOST . $request->getUrl());
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request->getMethod());
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
        $request->getAuthHeader(),
        ));

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request->getData());
    }


    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        var_dump($err);
        throw new FromRequestException('Cant make a request');
    }

    return $response;
}
```

In addition, `$request->getData()` correctly extracts the data from current request:
`$request->data = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Comment: Have you tried appending a newline character to the string returned from $request->getData() so that it knows the request is complete?

Comment: @JasonBoss actually no, I havent. I'll try it right away UPD. it didnt help :(

Comment: show us exactly what `$request->getData()` returns, do ```var_dump($request->getData());```, what do you get?

Comment: I get `string(32) "{"days_up_to":12,"territory":[]}"`

Comment: @hanshenrik added a comment above, and as I said, I already did a debugging thing printed out everything that could go wrong and its not the case, data is correct and not null if I'm not making it so

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the issue, when i execute this specific code:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:9999");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
        "auth-header: foo",
        ));

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"days_up_to":12,"territory":[]}');


    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
```

PHP/libcurl sends this specific request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
Accept: */*
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: application/json
auth-header: foo
Content-Length: 32

{"days_up_to":12,"territory":[]}
```

and if you look at line 7 of the request, the Content-Length header is present.

Comment: What php version you are at?

Comment: @WardS PHP 7.3.7 with libcurl 7.66.0 - but i have been using php/curl_ for many years, and i know that even back in the php 5 days, curl automatically added the `Content-Lenght` header for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.. still, what php & libcurl-version are you at?

Comment: PHP 7.2 and libcurl 7.58.0

Comment: @WardS can you contact me on facebook or something? contact details here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik?tab=profile  - i'd like to see what you're describing with my own eyes, if you catch me when i have time/am bored